# How to add a custom word to my domain URL for every request?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, drupal-6

Consider my domain name is

```
www.mydomain.com
```

Consider a page request

```
www.mydomain.com/user/register
```

I want to add a custom word after base URL for every request inside mydomain.com.example

```
www.mydomain.com/customword/
www.mydomain.com/customword/user/register
```

Can we do this using URL rewriting in htaccess file ?

Actually it should execute  'www.mydomain.com/user/register' internally...but externally the URL should look like www.mydomain.com/customword/user/register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the directory "register", and put an index file inside it that performs the action.

That's probably the simplest way without url rewriting anyway.

---

### UPDATE (since the question was updated)

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)/user/register/?$ user/register.php?customword=$1
```

register.php will receive a GET request:

```
//User went to www.mydomain/word/user/register
echo $_GET['customword']; // will return word in this case
```

Make sure that you have mod_rewrite enabled :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with htaccess

Here is an example which will add a trailing slash with url if it doesnt contain trailing slash

http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** formatting updated
If you are serving one site from this then the following should work:

Edit your `.htaccess` file to do a url rewrite

accessing `www.yourdomain.com/user/registry` will actually server content from `www.yourdomain.com/customword/user/registry`

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customword/<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /customword/$1
```

You haven't mentioned what kind of site you;re using..eg: PHP, MVC etc as you could do similar thing in there as well.