# I need to add custom word into my URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Assume this is my domain:

```
www.mydomain.com
```

The custom word should be after the domain, here's an example:

```
www.mydomain.com/[my-custom-word]/directory1?data1=1&data2=2
```

I would like this to become:

```
www.mydomain.com/directory1?data1=1&data2=2
```

I already tried the answer from this question:

[How to add a custom word to my domain URL for every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399483)

Here is my .htaccess code (based on the answer from the link attached):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)/directory1/?$ directory1?customword=$1
```

But this disregards the PHP other GET data passing from the URL, I only get the [my-custom-word] from GET data.

[my-custom-word] word is dynamic and I think it's not worth it to create a folder of [my-custom-word] based on every record I have in the DB.

Comment: Show your current .htaccess content in question and also what's the purpose of adding this custom word.

Comment: Hi sir, I updated my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your regex by placing hyphen at last or first position in character class and use a `QSA` flag to preserve your existing query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9.-]+)/directory1/?$ directory1/?customword=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This redirects me to

    www.mydomain.com/directory/?customword=[mycustom-word]

Comment: This is not a redirect but silent rewrite. And what's the problem in this rewrite? What was the full URL you tested in browser?

Comment: this is what I tested `www.mydomain.com/[my-custom-word]/directory` then it redirects me to `www.mydomain.com/directory/?customword=[mycustom-word]`

Comment: @jeck120591 What would be the desired outcome?

Comment: the outcome should be `www.mydomain.com/[my-custom-word]/directory`